# How to count rows in another table which contains foreign key and loop it foreach collection instance?

Tags: laravel

I have two tables which are connected each other.
their structures look like this.

modul_table

**id | user_id | title | slug | platform**

lecture_table

**id | user_id | modul_id | title | content**

I want to count how many rows in `lecture_table` where its `modul_id = $id`.
So this `$id` are the ids of my collection which retrieved from controller.

here's my controller:

```
public function index()
    {
        $modul = Modul::get();
        $arr_lecture = [];
        foreach ($modul as $key) {
            $lecture = Lecture::where('modul_id', $key->id)->count();
            array_push($arr_lecture, $lecture);
        }
        return view('func.lihatModul', compact('modul', 'arr_lecture'));
    }
```

and in my view :

```
@php $i = 0 @endphp
@foreach($modul as $key) 
<tr>
    <td>{{$key->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$key->title}}</td>
    <td>{{substr($key->desc, 0, 75)}}</td>
    <td>{{ $arr_lecture[$i++] }}</td>
@endforeach
```

and the result:

[image]

[image]

all my codes are working well, but is there any way just by using query builder or a function to do the same approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have defined the `lectures` relationship in your `Modul` model like so:

```
# Modul.php

public function lectures()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Lecture::class);
}
```

Then, you could simple do this in your `ModulController`:

```
public function index()
{
    $moduls = Modul::withCount('lectures')->get();
    //              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    return view('func.lihatModul')->withModuls($moduls);
}                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This will add the `lectures_count` attribute to each `$modul`, so you can access it in your Blade view like this:

```
@foreach($moduls as $modul) 
<tr>
    <td>{{ $modul->id }}</td>
    <td>{{ $modul->title }}</td>
    <td>{{ substr($modul->desc, 0, 75) }}</td>

    <td>{{ $modul->lectures_count }}</td> // <-----
@endforeach
```

Check the docs regarding this section: [Counting related models](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).

Comment: @RadenKriting glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the one-to-many relationships set up properly as it explains in the docs https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

So in your Modul.php model

```
public function lectures()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Lecture');
}
```

and in your Lecture.php model

```
public function modul()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Modul');
}
```

then you should just be able to do

`$modul = Modul::with('lectures')->get();`

Then in blade

```
@foreach($modul as $key) 
<tr>
    <td>{{$key->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$key->title}}</td>
    <td>{{substr($key->desc, 0, 75)}}</td>
    <td>{{ $key->lectures->count() }}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: this will not working since i dont have lecture_modul table

Comment: @RadenKriting You don't need it. It's a one to many relationship https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Answer (score 0):

If u want to leave your variant u don't need to use `array_push` better store value in array with `$key`

```
public function index()
    {
        $modul = Modul::get();
        $arr_lecture = [];
        foreach ($modul as $key) {
            $lecture = Lecture::where('modul_id', $key->id)->count();
            $arr_lecture[$key->id] = $lecture;
        }
        return view('func.lihatModul', compact('modul', 'arr_lecture'));
    }
```

now `$arr_lecture` will have correct keys. Next in view

```
@foreach($modul as $key) 
<tr>
    <td>{{$key->id}}</td>
    <td>{{$key->title}}</td>
    <td>{{substr($key->desc, 0, 75)}}</td>
    <td>{{ count($arr_lecture[key->id]) }}</td>
@endforeach
```

but Kennys version is really good

Comment: and u dont need @php to loop it through, ty for ur answer